# importing nltk in python 3.4.0

Tags: python

I am new to python and using python 3.4.0. I have installed `nltk` and `six` but I am getting an error when importing.I have also tried upgrading. Its up to date.

```
import nltk
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
     import nltk
     File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 128, in        <module>
    from nltk.chunk import *
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
    from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\chunk\api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from nltk.parse import ParserI
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
    from nltk.parse.malt import MaltParser
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 14, in <module>
    from six import text_type
    ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

Comment: how did you install those? using `pip`?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yeah